# Pyside (Qt) - How to query signal

Tags: qt, pyside

I need to query the signal related to the 'textEdited' connection and can't find how to.

```
# How the signal was created
myLineEditWidget.textEdited.connect(theSignalIwantToQuery)
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Can you explain your question better

Comment: I want to query the Function connected to a Signal emitted by a Widget

Comment: What do you mean by 'query the Function '?

Comment: Basically I want to convert the 'textEdited' signal into a 'returnPressed' signal with the same function connected to it. I cannot modify the source code so I would need to do this after the widget and connections were created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Signals aren't query-able. They instantaneously invoke functions they are connected to. Also the syntax doesn't work like that. It works [like this](http://wiki.qt.io/Signals_and_Slots_in_PySide).

Given this code:

```
def myFunction(self, text):
    print text

myLineEditWidget.textEdited.connect(myFunction)
```

In this case `textEdited` is the name of the signal. You can see [in the Qt documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#textEdited) for the `QLineEdit` widget it's listed under Signals. This code is connecting it to a function called `myFunction()` which is called when the condition occurs. So when the line edit widget has it's text edited, `myFunction()`, and any other functions (slots) connected to this signal, will be invoked.

Congratulations on discovering Qt and trying to get to grips with signals and slots though. It does take a little while to get your head round it, but it's well worth it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I wasn't very clear with the terms I used.

Comment: Actually I was trying to query the function called by a signal from a widget to be able to create a new signal connected to the function (and disconnect the function from the original signal). I will have to figure out something else, thank you !